# Debugging variable error with Java

Tags: java, swing, debugging, for-loop, char

I am trying to do this stuff. If a user enters "C:\Windows\system32\foo.txt" then the program will convert it to "C:\\Windows\\system32\\foo.txt". A front slash needs to be added to every other preceding slash. Here's what I have coded till now (only the section relevant):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String path = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the File path", "Word counter", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    for (int z=0;z<=path.length()-1;z++)
    {
        if (path.charAt(z) == '\\')
        {
            path.charAt(z) = "\\\\";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(path); // For knowing what's going on
}
}
```

Unfortunately it's not compiling, and I don't have a clue of what to do. Any possible help welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: If you get a compilation error question, don't you think you should **show** us the actual error message and indicate which line causes it? Kind of makes common sense, no?

Comment: *"Enter the File path"*  FUS (For User's Sake) offer a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) here!

Comment: Well Andrew your answer just worked the magic, I never knew about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying modify a String. Remember strings are immutable.

you can try something like

path.replace(oldChar, newChar) if you want to replace some chars.

Answer (score 1):

This: `path.charAt(z)` cannot be on the left side of an assignment statement. Instead concatenate your String or use a StringBuilder.

Or just use String's `replace(...)` method.